# How to create a Accordion dynamically inside Another Accordion

Tags: jquery

I am unable to get the whole accordion if it has got nested Accordions in it.

This is  my full example:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*, com.as400samplecode.util.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SSSS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var xmldocu = '<categories><category id="2" name="Pepsi" ><products><product id="858" name="7UP" price="24.4900" /><product id="860" name="Aquafina" price="24.4900" /></products></category><category id="4" name="Coke" ><products><product id="811" name="ThumpsUp" price="24.4900" /><product id="813" name="Maaza" price="24.4900" /></products></category></categories>' ;
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("div.accordian").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
    });

        $("div.accordian").accordion({
             activate: function(event, ui) {
            var selectedeleemnt = ui.newHeader.text();
            if(selectedeleemnt=="CoolDrinks")
            {

                $('#inner')
                .html(" \
                    <h3><a href='#'>First</a></h3><div>First</div> \
                    <h3><a href='#'>Second</a></h3><div>Second</div> \
                    <h3><a href='#'>Third</a></h3><div>Third</div>")
                .accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                collapsible: true,
                active: false,
            });

            }
            }
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
 <%
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("CoolDrinks");
        list.add("Snacks");
        list.add("Other");
        %>

<div id="faqs-container" class="accordian">

<%
for(String item : list)
{
    %>
     <h3><a href="#"><%=item%></a></h3>

      <div id="inner">

    </div>
    <%
}
%>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can i please get any help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#inner` doesn't need a class of `accordion` and if you are just appending html like that I wouldn't bother chaining the appends, I would just use `html()` and then chain the accordion to the end:

```
$('#inner')
    .html(" \
        <h3><a href='#'>First</a></h3><div>First</div> \
        <h3><a href='#'>Second</a></h3><div>Second</div> \
        <h3><a href='#'>Third</a></h3><div>Third</div>")
    .accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/VgKqD/73/)

[Example if you want to use append](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/VgKqD/72/)

Comment: I used you approach , but i couldn't show the whole content in Accordian , its showing up with a scrollbar , please see the pictute here http://i57.tinypic.com/2m43k08.png

Comment: Hi Pete , On click of a Accordian element , i capturing that element and using your code to dynamically create Accordians as required . but the problem is that when its clicked twice on that Element they are being convert to text from Accordians . could you please tell me why .

Comment: sorry, was on lunch.  could you update the fiddle with an example

Comment: Try this - I would only insert it once otherwise you are adding extra overheads for nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DBYLk/1/

Comment: If you need to add it every click then you will need to make a new accordion container - as you have already bound the accordion to the #inner div, it won't rebind to the new contents so I would just add it seperately like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DBYLk/2/

Comment: First of thank you very very much , both works perfectly , If you dont mind , i have one more question the nested Accordian(say First in this case) can also have Accordians (depends on the data fetched dynamically) , in that case how can i bind data to the nested Accordian (First in our case ) because as div named  inner is fixed in above  case .

Comment: so you would taget the div you want to put the content in with an id and then load the html into it: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DBYLk/4/.  If you can't giv the divs an id the try this: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DBYLk/5/

Comment: Pete i mean that , i am parsing an xml file , if the  elements has a Category , then i need to keep on create an Accordian as per that . Say for example PopCorn has been seleted , two Accordians will be shown with Chilli Flavour , Normal Flavour , if Chilli Flavour is selected , i need to show another two Acordians Big Bucket or Small Bucket then finally the image .

Comment: pete , the Sub List and Sub List stuff should be also Accordians .

Comment: Pete , Assume that in place of One there  are CoolDrinks , Snacks Accordians shown by default .
If i click on cool Drink Accordian  , it must show two Accordians pepsi and Cokde and once if i select pepsi Accordian , it must show Tin or Bottle Accodians and finally if i select Tin Accordian it will show some text content .

Comment: Pete , on click of the First Accordian , the subelements needs to be shown also as Accordians (sublist and And Another ) in our case

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DBYLk/14/ or example with accordion that doen't load another accordion http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DBYLk/15/

Comment: I can't ask for more , thank you very very much , God sent you for me .This is what i wanted .

Comment: ya got it . this will be useful later when i am implementing it . Thank you very much Pete . you saved me .

Comment: Hi Pete , i am struck up with a big issue , please refer to fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/K646y/4/ , I have a question , checkboxes that were selected were lost when clicked on menu bar . If Snacks is selected

Snacks ---->Puffs --->Veg---> and check any checkbox

And finally then if we Click on Beverages .

The issue is that the checkboxes that were selected under Snacks aren't being rembered .

Please let me know how can it remember the checkboxes selected in this case ??

Comment: Hi Kiran, you should post a new question for this but basically you would be looking at using cookies

Comment: Ya , i know that felling sorry , but i  was desperetely looking for an answer so , i can't go for cookies as this is a phonegap (Mobile) based so cant use cookies or local storage .

Comment: ah not too sure about phonegap stuff, so afraid I can't really help on this part.  Sorry

Comment: Phonegap is nothing but HTML with javascript only . but cant use cookies or localstorage . and there is no difference at all compared to web application.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is not processed as an accordion, because you called the processing function before the append happened.
you have to call the accordion function afterwards for the appended accordion div in order for jquery to generate the html of an accordion so that it can work.

example:

```
$('#x').click(function () {
    $('#y').append('<div class="accordian"><h3>A3</h3><div></div></div>');

    $("#y").children('.accordian').accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgKqD/68/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just a matter of calling the accordion plugin after all the `appends` have been made  
**New HTML:**

```
<div id="faqs-container" class="accordian">
     <h3><a href="#">ASD</a></h3>
     <div id="inner" class="accordian">

     </div>
</div>
```

**New jQuery:**

```
$("#inner")
    .append("<h3><a href='#'>First</a></h3><div>First</div>")
    .append("<h3><a href='#'>Second</a></h3><div>Second</div>")
    .append("<h3><a href='#'>Third</a></h3><div>Third</div>");

$("div.accordian").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
});
```

In order to get the same css design as in the fiddle, you will have to include the jQuery UI CSS file in your `head` tag like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

And here is a demo **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VgKqD/70/)**

Comment: Thank you very much , how can i use the same css file jsfiddle is using , because i am getting that in differetn way .

Comment: You will have to include the jQuery-UI CSS file, I will update my answer to include that as well

Comment: Even though i used the css file yu provided , its not reflecting to the css present in js fiddle , i have updated my question , can you pelase tell me why .

Comment: If you run the updated part of my question , there is no css applied at all .

Comment: That is because you have a lot of unnecessary javascript code in there. Here is all you need to get the accordion to work properly: [link](http://codeshare.io/BugAF)