# Am I creating my Accordion multiple times?

Tags: jquery

I got this code from net which i am using to create Accordians inside Accordians (nested Accordians).

I am very much new to javascript and frankly i couldn't understand some pieces of code in this , but still i am using as it meets my requirement .

Please see the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/MYD4M/2/

Once you clcik the Accordian , it will be creating nested Accordian dynamically

Could you please tell me , is this code is efficient .

I mean Am i registering with the registering with the Accordian and Accordian  event every time ??

(below piece of code)

```
$("div.accordian").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    clearStyle: true,
    active: false,
});

$("div.accordian").accordion({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        setStuff(event, ui);
    }
});
```

If there are mistakes please let me know  , so that i can correct them .
or if its fine , i shall continue using this code .

Comment: do you need to load the sub accordions on the fly?  I seem to recall writing that piece of code for someone that was doing an ajax call to populate the sub accordions when the header was clicked.  Personally I wouldn't have done it that way

Comment: I don't see the include for your accordion js file in that fiddle.

Comment: @SeanKendle accordion is part of [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) (which is ticked as inlcuded in the options on the left of the fiddle)

Comment: @Pete , no problem ,  So it was you who kept that fiddle , i am very thankful to you , you made my work much simpler

Comment: @Pete Ah, I haven't used UI much, I always create my own elements like that.

Comment: @user3674364 yeah it was in response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778811/how-to-create-a-accordion-dynamically-inside-another-accordion/23781795#23781795), if you follow the comments through, you get to the version you found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating it twice, with two different sets of parameters.

Just change it to this:

```
$("div.accordian").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    autoHeight: true,
    collapsible: true,
    clearStyle: true,
    active: true,
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        setStuff(event, ui);
    }
});
```

Also, note that you have an extra comma in your first declaration!   The last parameter shouldn't have a comma after it.

Comment: It was set to active `false`??  I changed that.  Also, changed autoheight to `true`.

Comment: can i initially hide the Accordian One , and show that only when clciked on a button ??

Comment: Looks like your code is creating a lot of different inner accordions.  Not sure if that's what you're going for.

Comment: Yes this is what i required .

Comment: I changed the cursor to be the normal mouse pointer over that "button" I made: http://jsfiddle.net/ueW9H/5/

Comment: @user3674364 - thanks for accepting, can you upvote, please?  I upvoted you so you now have the required reputation!  ^_-

Comment: Please see the jsfiddle here , on click of the tab , i need to show the Accordian , http://jsfiddle.net/LxztT/ is that possible ??

Comment: I get this error in my console (hit F12 to bring up your debugging console, if you have Chrome or Firebug, if not, get Firebug!)

`activateEvent is not defined`

Comment: ya , how to fix that ?? because on click of the tab only i want to show the Accordian any idea ??

Comment: why cant we do  setStuff(activateEvent, activateUi); directly ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with those, I don't use the jQuery UI accordion, so I'm not exactly sure what those are supposed to refer to.